# Java program uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I was writing a program in our activity in school and when I compile I get the following error:

[image]

I am also using notepad++ to compile
This is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

        arrayList.add("A");

        arrayList.add("B");

        arrayList.add("C");

        arrayList.add("D");

        arrayList.add("E");

        System.out.println("Before Reverse Order: " + arrayList);

        Collections.reverse(arrayList);

        System.out.println("After Reverse Order: " + arrayList);

    }

}
```

I am new to learning java so any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) with the `ArrayList`

replace it with

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

**More info** : [***What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)